# How to empty an Array of arrays in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which is an array of arrays. I want to empty the array as in, get rid of all the arrays with in that array. How would I accomplish that? Thanks

I have tried setting it to new but that does not seem to work for me. I have also tried something like finalSetB.length = 0.

I get no errors but the array is just piling up and is slowing my next procedure down and not returning the expected results. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: please add the code. setting `length` to zero empties the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `array.splice`. You can use it to remove elements from array. You can find documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```
var  arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
arr.splice(0, 4); // will remove 4 elements from 0th index
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `array.splice(0, array.length);`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the array to an empty array?
Just do:

```
array = [];
```

Comment: This will create a new array, other references to the original array will remain unmodified